# Blazor FileStream stream is null after saving file to disk

Tags: c#, blazor

So I'm trying to copy a stream into another stream with file.CopyToAsync but the destination stream fs returns a length of 0 after it has been saved to disk.

```
FileUploads fup = new FileUploads();
Stream file = e.File.OpenReadStream(10240000);

var path = @"C:\BlazorUploads\" + e.File.Name;

FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
file.CopyToAsync(fs);

fup.FileStream = fs;
fup.FileName = e.File.Name;
fup.ContentType = e.File.ContentType;
fups.Add(fup);
```

I have tried several ways and with and without await to do this but have had no luck.

Comment: From what I understand you def need to await, plus *fs* should be opened with async operation in *Create*

Comment: Thanks Maciek, can you give me an example of how I do that please?

Comment: No, this ought to work in an `async void` as well. And on Blazor-server you can use non-async I/O.

Comment: Why are you specifying a 10MB buffer size?

Comment: Dai, the buffer size is the max file size.